# Optionals: What's the difference between [String?] and [String]?

Tags: ios, swift

Essentially what is the difference between `[String?]` and `[String]?`
If I define an array like `var myStringArray:[String?]`I don't need use `!` to unwrap it, but when I define array as `var myStringArray:[String]?` I have to force unwrap it using `!`
What Am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[String?]` is an array of optional strings. Array cannot be nil but strings can.
`[String]?` is an optional array of strings. Array can be nil but strings can't.

For `[String?]` you do not have to unwrap the array but you have to unwrap each string in the array. For `[String]?` you need to unwrap the array before using it but not the strings in the array.

```
let arrayOfOptionalStrings: [String?] = [ "a", nil, "c" ]

for string in arrayOfOptionalStrings {
    if let string = string {
        print(string)
    }
}
```

---

```
var optionalArrayOfStrings: [String]? = [ "a", "b", "c" ]

if let array = optionalArrayOfStrings {
    for string in array {
        print(string)
    }
}

optionalArrayOfStrings = nil
```

Comment: Thank you It makes sense now! Helped me!

Answer (score 3):

`[String?]` is an *array* of *Optional Strings*. The array itself is not an Optional but contains Optionals.

`[String]?` is an *Optional array* of *Strings*. The array itself is an Optional, containing non-Optionals.

Answer (score 2):

for [String]? you're creating an optional Array of strings, the array is an optional.

for [String?] you're creating an Array of string optionals, each index value is a optional string